# Call class/ JPanel from Main Project?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I've finished my store management program with many classes (many JForm panels actually. Thanks to people in this forum whom helped me so much).
I just need to call JPanel `Login` when I click Run Project.
Any idea how to call it? what code I have to insert to main project?

Comment: Please post any code snippet and narrow down the problem.

Comment: I just want to call my jpanel form named `login`  from main project. How to call it?

Comment: create object of `JPanel` and add it to `JFrame` and set that `JFrame` visible...as you cannot open `JPanel` as a dialog or `Window`...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display `JPanel` independently.

So you have to create a `JFrame` and then add this `JPanel` object to this `JFrame` and then display the `JFrame`.

write these lines in your `main method`.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); // as per your requirement.
frame.add(new Login(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

it will work properly.

Comment: Do i have to import something?

Comment: It shows syntax error `cannot find symbol class BorderLayout`

Comment: yap... `java.awt.BorderLayout, javax.swing.JFrame`...and done.

Comment: It shows error on console `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container`

Comment: The syntax please? i'm newbie.

Comment: provide me `Login.java` code...without that, i can't say anything without that...

Comment: in that case write only `new Login().setVisible(true);` in your `main method`...no need to write above code..

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("MyTitle");
myFrame.setSize(width, height);
myFrame.setLocation(x, y);
myFrame.setContentPane(new Login());
myFrame.setVisible(true);    
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// if you want add your jcomponent
myFrame.getContentPane().add(yourJComponent);
```

try it!

If you want add JComponent(JButton)

```
JButton myBtn = new JButton("btn name");
myBtn.setLocation(x, y);
myFrame.getContentPane().add(myBtn);
```

If you want add JComponent(JText)

```
JText myText = new JText("text");
myText.setLocation(x, y);
myFrame.getContentPane().add(myText);
```

JComponent [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html]

Comment: What does the means of `(YourComponent)`? What i have to put in there? (Newbie + foreigner of english)